# I'm trying to convert database value to json

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to convert database value to json
I had do some array before encode to json, but it not return like what i want,
someone please help me
My code is some thing like this

```
  function createDataJson($ref){
  $master_data = array();
  // $data = array();
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT dataCode FROM tbl_master WHERE dataRefServices = '$ref'");
  if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
      $dataCode = $row['dataCode'];
      $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT asKey,asValue FROM tbl_master WHERE dataCode = '$dataCode' AND dataRefServices = '$ref'");
      if(mysql_num_rows($sql2)){
        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)) {
          $asKey = $row2['asKey'];
          $asValue = $row2['asValue'];
          $data->$asKey=$asValue;
        }
          $dat[] = $data;
      }
      $master_data = $dat;
    }
  }

  return json_encode($master_data);
}
```

and it return like this, it just duplicate the last array

```
    [
  {
    "code": "IT - 0004",
    "main": "12",
    "child": "14",
    "name": "Laptop",
    "brand": "Lenovo"
  }, {
    "code": "IT - 0004",
    "main": "12",
    "child": "14",
    "name": "Laptop",
    "brand": "Lenovo"
  }
]
```

The format I'm looking for is something like this:

```
  [
    {
    "code": "IT - 0001",
    "main": "12",
    "child": "14",
    "name": "Pavillion 15",
    "brand": "Asus"
  }, {
    "code": "IT - 0002",
    "main": "12",
    "child": "14",
    "name": "Envy 13",
    "brand": "HP"
  }
 ]
```

From this table:

[image]

Please help me, really looking for it

can someone assist me on this , please. i'm stuck here. hehehe

Comment: First get the data from database as array then use json_encode() method to convert that array into json.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning JSON from a PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script)

Answer (score 0):

Use json_encode to convert array to json.

```
echo json_encode($array_of_data_from_database);
```

This will send the JSON Data as response.

Comment: [
  {
    "code": "IT - 0004",
    "main": "12",
    "child": "14",
    "name": "Laptop",
    "brand": "Lenovo"
  }, {
    "code": "IT - 0004",
    "main": "12",
    "child": "14",
    "name": "Laptop",
    "brand": "Lenovo"
  }, {
    "code": "IT - 0004",
    "main": "12",
    "child": "14",
    "name": "Laptop",
    "brand": "Lenovo"
  }, {
    "code": "IT - 0004",
    "main": "12",
    "child": "14",
    "name": "Laptop",
    "brand": "Lenovo"
  }
]

Comment: it return that way